# Slow Tomcat 7 deployment with Spring 3.2.4 upgrade

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

We recently upgraded from Spring 3.0 to Spring 3.2.4. With Spring 3.0 starting tomcat would take under a minute. After upgrading to 3.2.4, it now takes 4 minutes. The step that takes time is

Sep 09, 2013 3:00:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /tomcat/webapps/ROOT

It takes close to 4 minutes for the next statement

Sep 09, 2013 3:04:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init

This is on Tomcat 7.0.41. Any ideas on what to look for?

**Edit: Further debugging indicates that this issue is specific to Tomcat 7 + Spring 3.2. Tomcat 6 + Spring 3.2 doesn't have the performance issue. Tomcat 7 + Spring 3.0 is also ok.**

Comment: There is something wrong with your DB setup? I use Tomcat Pool too and it serves me very well.

Comment: Michael - the same db setup with Spring 3.0 doesn't have an issue, so I don't believe it's DB related

Comment: How does it come then the init requires 4 min? Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes. org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory /tomcat/webapps/ROOT what takes 4 minutes, not the connection pool init.

Comment: I would recommend to update to 3.1 first and see whether the problem is already there and go up by patch version by patch version. Your leap is too big to find the root cause.